# activate divs in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm not a jQuery pro but i sample it as much as i can.

Fiddle Demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UqgXc/17/)

I want to activate 3 animations consecutively.

Steps:

1. Expand the navigation div B from 200 to 250 with a speed from 500
2. Then move the navigation div A from top 0 to top 50
3. At the same time as 2. Finally slide in the sub navigation div C from top -50 to top 50
4. When I click another navigation div the steps 1-3 closed backwards.

   ```
   $(function(){
   $('.a').click(
   function(){
           $(".b").stop().animate(
               {width:"250px"},
               500,
               function(){
                   $('.b').stop().animate({width:"toggle"});
               }
           );  
   },
   $(".a").stop().animate(
               {top:"50px"},
               500,
               function(){
                   $('.b').stop().animate({top:"toggle"});
               }
           );  
   },
   function(){
       $('.c').stop().animate(
           {show:"yes"},
           500,
           function(){
                $(".a").stop().animate(
                    {backgroundPosition:"left 0"}
                    ,500
                )
           }
       );
    }
    );

    });
   ```

Is there any solution that fix my problem?

Please look at the Picture in the fiddle :) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really getting the details of what you want. But here is an example of how you can run animations consecutively on your divs:

```
var $a = $(".a"),
    $b = $(".b"),
    $c = $(".c");

function anim1() {
    $b.animate({width: 250}, {duration: 500, complete: anim2});
}

function anim2() {
    $a.animate({top:"0px"}, {duration: 500, complete: anim3});
}

function anim3() {
    $c.animate({top: "0px"}, 500);
}

anim1();
```

Also, if you want to move your divs, you have to make them `position: relative` or [something](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp). Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UqgXc/23/).